# Sendgrid Newsletter App Custom Tags

Tags: html, email, tags, sendgrid

Anyone know of a doc with the default custom tags for email templates for Sendgrid? I know they have [UNSUB] and I'm using it.

I want Forward to Friend, View in Browser, etc...

I am uploading my own template code, not using the design editor. Do I have to create these? For view in browser, do I have to host my page and point to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tags for unsubscribe and view in browser should be `[unsubscribe]` and `[weblink]` respectively.  Not sure why that's not documented, but I've opened up a ticket to get that fixed.  Thanks for the heads up!

**Edit:**

I dug a little deeper and have a full list of built in tags:

- weblink
- email
- unsubscribe

Also, if you define custom column headers on your lists, you can refer to those in the same manner.  (Ex. If you add shoe size to each person in your list, you could do `[shoe_size]`)

And the closing tip is that if you're editing in HTML-mode, you need to follow the full `href` convention:

```
<a href="[unsubscribe]" ...
```

Comment: Awesome! Yeah, the full anchor href is similar to MailChimp. (and most other apps) Thanks for the help.